# Online Quote Page

Tags: php, javascript, email, quote

I have three input boxes; First Name / Last Name / E-Mail Address

A user can select from three groups of radio Buttons;

```
Service 1: Option 1 / Option 2 / Option 3
Service 2: Option 1 / Option 2 / Option 3
Service 3: Option 1 / Option 2 / Option 3
```

As part of the three services each option has a numeric value. One option from the three services should be selected. Each option in each section is then added to give a total.

Finally details of First Name/Last Name/E-mail Address are sent to a particular e-mail address. The names of the options selected as well as the total value is sent also to that particular e-mail address.

Comment: ~ Also, [welcome to StackOverflow](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), and while it will take you some time to get the hang of the site, know that you can leave a comment by clicking the comment button underneath a message or another comment, you can reply to someone by putting @ before their name (as I did with yours here) and you can edit your own question to add more detail. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3):

So basically you're looking to give someone the option to mail themselves a quote/estimate for services to be done and let them choose the level of service they're looking for, then you want to log that info to a database and send them a copy of the email that you just generated, right?

So the problem becomes then three pieces:

1. Get the data from the webpage back into PHP in a parseable format (sounds like you've got this one licked)
2. Create an email to send data to that person with formatting and such (sounds like what you really want)
3. Store the record in the DB (easy enough for most PHP devs to figure out pretty quickly).

Actually, I'm gonna go with you don't know how to do step one, and were hoping someone else could guide you to steps two and three, but to you they sounded like they were all one step, does that sound about right?

Before I keep going, a little feedback on how well I've read the situation would be nice.

protip: on this site, being more explicit at the cost of sounding like you're giving out business details [you're not] is a good thing. We don't care if you are the lead designer for JiffyLube USA. Just tell us what you're ACTUALLY trying to do and we can help you a lot better.